# Display avatar for each user in profile Laravel 5.5

Tags: php, laravel, profile, avatar

Hello Everyone i'm having a little problem with my app. I can display the Auth::user avatar but when i get into another profile "another account profile" i get that profile but with the Auth::user avatar. My question is, how can i display the avatar of every registered user in each profile?

This is my ProfileController method to get into profiles.

```
public function profile($username)
{
  $user = User::where('username', $username)->firstOrFail();
  $users = User
          ::join('posts', 'posts.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
          ->join('comments', 'comments.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
          ->select('posts.title', 'posts.user_id as users.name', 'comments.comment', 'comments.created_at', 'users.name')
          ->get()
          ->first();
  return view('profile.index', ['user' => Auth::user()] )->withUsers($users);
}
```

The Route

```
Route::get('profile/{username}', 'ProfileController@profile')->name('profile');
```

How i display the picture in Profile Vie

```
<figure>
 <img class="img-responsive img-circle" src="/uploads/avatars/{{ $user->profilepic }}" alt="Foto de perfil{{ Auth::user()->profilepic }}, {{ Auth::user()->name }}">
</figure>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You're always passing the authenticated user to the view. So, change this:

```
['user' => Auth::user()]
```

To:

```
['user' => $user]
```

Also, I think you should change the `alt` text:

```
{{ $user->profilepic }}, {{ $user->name }}
```

Instead of:

```
{{ Auth::user()->profilepic }}, {{ Auth::user()->name }}
```